# How do I obtain statistics about closures, deletions and migrations?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I would like to know how many questions were closed between 1-1-2017 and the present: I would like to compare the official "reason" esp. "language specific" vs. "trees" vs. "opinion". I believe that this is possible and doesn't require moderator intervention, but I don't know how to do it. I'm not requesting the specific answer, I'm asking for a description of the method, if it is reasonably possible to describe in relatively non-technical terms (not "any professional programmer would understand this").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/), it's possible to find out how many questions were closed for each of the top-level reasons. [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/linguistics/query/1361440/close-reasons-by-frequency?dateFrom=2017-01-01) does that; you can easily change the start date if you want e.g. the figures since 2020.

| Reason | Questions closed |
| --- | --- |
| Off-topic | 190 |
| Needs details or clarity | 69 |
| Duplicate of... | 58 |
| Needs more focus | 49 |
| Opinion-based | 33 |

Unfortunately, the second-level reasons (language-specific, identification/translation, syntax trees) are not available in SEDE; see [Please add the individual close-as-off-topic reason in the Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/297750/295232).

The information *is* available (for individual questions) in the API, e.g. [this example](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids#order=desc&sort=activity&ids=37989&filter=!9_bDDw2Vc&site=linguistics&run=true). But I completely understand that's completely off-limits for you; it would even take *me* an hour or so to compile the data (that SEDE query only took me a few minutes).